# How do I limit it to 5 attempts and how they get 10 points added to their score if they guess correct, and they lose 1 point for wrong guess?

Tags: python

Problem: (Python) Write a program that asks the user to guess a random number between 1 and 10. If they guess right, they get 10 points added to their score, and they lose 1 point for an incorrect guess. Give the user five numbers to guess and print their score after all the guessing is done.

fs: I already have this code below, my problem now is how do I limit it to 5 attempts, also how to add "score system" like they get 10 points added to their score if they guess right, and they lose 1 point for an incorrect guess.

My code:

```
import random
target_num, guess_num = random.randint(1, 10), 0
while target_num != guess_num:
    guess_num = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 10 until you get it right : '))
print('Well guessed!')
```

Comment: Use another variable to keep track of score. then workout which cases it needs to be incremented or decremented

Answer (score 0):

Use `attempt` variable to track how many times the user has guessed.

Use `score` variable to track the accumulated score from guessing.

```
import random
target_num, guess_num = random.randint(1, 10), 0
attempt = 0
score = 0
while attempt < 5:
    attempt += 1
    guess_num = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 10: '))
    if target_num == guess_num:
        score += 10
        print('Correct! You get +10 points')
    else:
        score -= 1
        print('Wrong! You get -1 point')
print("Your score: ", score, " points.")
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do it like this -

```
import random
target_num, guess_num, tries, score= random.randint(1, 10), 0, 5, 0
for i in range(tries):
    guess_num = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 10 until you get it right : '))
    if guess_num == target_num: 
       print('Well guessed!')
       score+=10
    else:
        score-=1
print(f'Your final score is {score}')
```

Comment: There's no point in calculating the score if you aren't going to do anything with it. You should at least print it out

Comment: Good point, editing my answer